# Is every set with sign measure non-negative is a positive set?

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Today, we studied that

a set $A$ is positive set if $\lambda(B)\geq0$ for every measurable subset $B$ of $A$.

a set $A$ is negative set if $\lambda(B)\leq0$ for every measurable subset $B$ of $A$.

a set $A$ is null if $A$ is both positive and negative.

Which made me think is every set $A$ with $\lambda(A)\geq0$ is positive?

Also, is every set $A$ with $\lambda(A)=0$ is null set?

Comment: Suppose $\lambda(B)=\sum\limits_{b \in B} 1_{b>0} - 1_{b<0}$ and $A=\{-1,0,1,2\}$.  Then $\lambda(A)=2-1=1>0$ but $\{-1\} \subset A$ and $\lambda(\{-1\})=-1<0$

Comment: @Henry ,What about the null case?

Comment: Take the example $\lambda(B)=\sum\limits_{b \in B} 1_{b>0} - 1_{b<0}$ again but with $A=\{-1,0,1\}$.  It looks to me as if $\lambda(A)=1-1=0$ but $A$ is neither positive nor negative and so not null

Comment: Thank you. Is there another definition of $\lambda$ which does the same thing?

Comment: I suspect for most signed measures which actually take both strictly positive and strictly negative values then you may be able to find such an $A$